# OpenERP(Odoo) How to customize MRP module to include manufacturing process Analysis?

Tags: module, odoo, reporting, erp

My company wants to track **(measure)** **suppliers (raw material) quality**.

In **each production** process there are **different suppliers involved and in the production process** some raw materials will not pass the quality measure, so we want to identify who is better supplier **according to their product quality in production.**

I have come up with the following idea. For each production we record the products involved, there quality status and there supplier, and finally for each production make summery (analysis) of the production process . . .

By doing this we can identify who is better supplier by looking at the result of different production analysis.

My question is how can I do this in Odoo(openERP)? I have looked at the MRP module and there is no such thing . . . **would you inform me some other (better) module to implement my requirement?**

**What is your general suggestion(solution) to implement this requirement?**

How can **I modify the Reporting Module**,It have sales, purchase, HR analysis how can I **add Manufacturing analysis there?**

if required the company is abattoirs (Slaughterhouse)company that produce carcasses form goat ,cow, sheep . . . we want to track animal suppliers because in production process some animals fail quality measures.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to inherit the Odoo app [**mrp_operations**](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/mrp_operations), as this module is responsible for adding the Manufacturing order **operation** based on Routing configured on BoM and reason being that you need to add some quality measure and different factor involved in production process/operations.

> For Requirement  **different suppliers involved and in the production process** this is has multiple solution:

1. Each raw materials is defined on BoM will automatically create **Procurement order** to supply the raw material and configure each raw material Product with  Make to Order, Buy policy so this will create Purchase Order for supplier, but if you install the app : [**purchase_requisition**](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/purchase_requisition), this will let you receive multiple requisition and then choose best supplier based on that. And then you can store that supplier on related manufacturing suggesting the best supplier for the operations.
2. Second way is complex is to overload procurement generation for each supplier and then from Manufacturing Order based on each raw material add some workflow implementation to generate the procurement and then acquire the raw materials based on quality measure you have. But this will take more implementation efforts and time and not cost effective too ;). In this way too you need to store measure and factors in operations only.

This are more primitive idea here based on what you explain. If i were you then prefer first idea as I will end up are re-using certified module which will  future migration efforts (easy migration) and maintainability (customized code  maintainability) will reduce.

> And for requirement **for each production make summery (analysis) of the production process**

Once you have one of the implementation is ready, you know that you storing all performance measure in operations Model. With this fact you can Statistical Report or analysis report based on operations model or more simply you can also create [**Business Intelligence (Graph/Pivot views)**](https://www.odoo.com/page/business-intelligence).

- Example to create the Analysis [report is here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/add-more-fields-to-pos-order-analysis-report-17156) (you need excellent SQl skills here for this for faster and optional performance as this are database views.).
- How to create to create the [Graph/Pivot view](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html) (scroll to graph view).

The implementation can be complex as you going to very specific requirements.

Bests,